# Is the there a KiCAD plugin for making automatic board outlines?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

Is there a plugin for kicad that can make simple shaped board outlines automatically? For example rectangles, rectangles with rounded edges etc.

I think that could be super usefull. Beacuse at the moment I edit the cooardinates of the lines manually to do precise cutouts.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I prefer to edit coordinates anyways - that way you know the exact dimensions.

Comment: There are templates that do this

Comment: if you're doing "simple" shapes made from orthogonal lines and circular arcs, can you simply change the snap-to grid to a pitch that would make it easier for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, rather than a plug in, you can use an external graphics package and create the PCB outline there.  I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), export the image via a `.dxf` file and then import as a graphic. Others might use Adobe Illustrator, and there are even more others than can export `.dxf`. Obviously AutoCad/SolidWorks and their derivatives/competitors.

So do this:-

[image: import]

To produce this:-

[image: pcb]

A point to note is that no matter how good a plug-in would be, it would still be a functional compromise when compared to a dedicated CAD/graphics package. I've had boards manufactured via this process and it's perfectly accurate. Just don't get too creative because you have to bear in mind the manufacturing capability of the board houses. They usually have a capabilities page [somewhere](https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/Capabilities).

Comment: yep. Also, for generating DXF files for complex CAD situation (well defined corners, constrained dimensions etc): LibreCAD if you feel like using a classical pen-paper-ruler construction drawing tool, FreeCAD if you're doing 3D modelling of an enclosure anyway and want things to be parameterizable.

Comment: This was super usefull thanks. I will just do it in solidworks and exort dxf now.

Comment: As a counterpoint, consider that the pcb outline and hole pattern must interface with mechanical parts that someone must fabricate, there must be drawings prepared with dimensions and tolerances etc. If you design a shape with all position/size dims a multiple of 0.1mm (or inch multiples in US) etc, and use standard tolerances, it makes it easy for everyone.